# System.Windows.Controls.Button image as content using WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is the code and the image is not showing. If I use the text content it shows up but the image will not. What am I missing?

```
            //Begin btnLine Code.
             btnLine = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
            // Create the image element.
            Image simpleImage = new Image();    
            simpleImage.Width = 200;
            simpleImage.Margin = new Thickness(5);

            // Create source.
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            // BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block.
            bi.BeginInit();

            bi.UriSource = new Uri(InstallDir+@"\ToolbarImages\line1.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            bi.EndInit();
            // Set the image source.
            simpleImage.Source = bi;

            btnLine.Content= bi;//image button Does not work
            //btnLine.Content= simpleImage;//image button Does not work
            //btnLine.Content= "o-o";//text button Does work

            btnLine.Click += btnLine_Click;
            chartWindow.MainMenu.Add(btnLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
btnLine.Content= bi;
```

to

```
btnLine.Content= simpleImage;
```

Comment: also make sure Build Action is set to Content, and Copy To Output Directory to Always for your image.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is much easier to do these things in XAML. it is fairly straight forward to set an image to a a local resource. This is a simple version how.

```
 <Grid>
    <Button>
        <Image Source="ToolbarImages\image1.jpg"/>
    </Button>
 </Grid>
```

If you are looking for a dynamic way to do this, you should use a binding on the source image that way you are leveraging the power of wpf.